# Timeout between Heroku app and AWS Postgres db

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, amazon-ec2

I've got an app hosted on heroku that's running just fine. The db, however is an RDS db running on EC2.

When I query the db locally I don't have any issues. However, after pushing the app to Heroku I'm getting timeout errors.

```
2015-11-18T06:04:16.098644+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-18 06:04:16 +0000] [3] [DEBUG] 2 workers
2015-11-18T06:04:17.100133+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-18 06:04:17 +0000] [3] [DEBUG] 2 workers
2015-11-18T06:04:17.519180+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/login" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=4cfb2d94-e5b8-467e-9949-8887a69c14f5 fwd="71.215.85.126" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2015-11-18T06:04:18.101610+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-18 06:04:18 +0000] [3] [DEBUG] 2 workers
2015-11-18T06:04:19.110720+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-11-18 06:04:19 +0000] [3] [DEBUG] 2 workers
```

I've looked around and most posts mention large queries but when I run these queries locally they come back within a second because they're not that large.

Below is my code for `/login`. To debug I added `x = User.query.all()` to see if I could do a basic query and because there is only 1 user but I'm still getting the timeout.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    x = User.query.all()
    for i in x:
        print i
    if request.method == "POST":
        #get all of the form fields
        searchword = request.form.get('search', '')
        registeredEmail = request.form.get('emailInput', '')
        registeredPassword = request.form.get('passwordInput', '')
        x = User.query.filter_by(email=registeredEmail).first()
        if searchword:
            return redirect('/search/{}'.format(searchword))
        if x and x.email and check_password_hash(x.password, registeredPassword):
            error = "User Exists! {}".format(x.email)
            if request.form.get('remember-me') == 'on':
                login_user(x, remember=True)
            else:
                login_user(x)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            error = "Username/Password combo does not match"
            return render_template('login.html', error=error)
    elif current_user.get_id():
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        return render_template('login.html', logged_in=current_user.is_authenticated)
```

I know that I *could* be using the native postgres db that Heroku offers but I should be able to get this running without issue.

Comment: Can the app connect to the DB at all, even for trivial queries? Are your security groups configured to let it?

Comment: I'm getting this error: `OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out Is the server running on host "my-db.cistvnnfekkh.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (52.27.234.240) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Comment: Sounds like you didn't configure your RDs security groups to allow connections from your heroku appserver then

Comment: I believe I've set up the security groups to allow all traffic - http://imgur.com/EAZ8Cnx